# Get Data from University LMS

Tags: azure-web-app-service, vercel

I want to create a website like this https://www.iamasad.xyz/uaf-gpa-cgpa-calculator/. It gets data from the university lms, calculates gpa and cgpa based on registration number and then show to the user. it works like [cgpa calculator](https://www.iamasad.xyz/uaf-gpa-cgpa-calculator/) How it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

To create website as per the above requirement You can refer to this the [***GitHub***](https://github.com/jomefavourite/CGPA-Result-Forecaster) sample .

This sample works to create GPA/CGPA calculator of students by using their registration number and gives us the result semester wise as well.

For more information please refer to this
[***GitHub samples***](https://github.com/topics/cgpa-calculator).